# Ember: Helper inside Component renders undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have component which renders a grid and it uses a helper to render each row. I'm getting `undefined` instaed of actual data. If I directly render the data without the helper the actual data is rendered. Please find the code below

### Gird Comp

```
{{#each data in dataValues}}
    {{ log " grid-comp "  data.title //title is rendered correctly}}
    {{grid-row data}}
{{/each}}
```

### Grid Row Helper

```
export function gridRow(data) {
    console.log(data.title); //undefined
    var row;
    row='<tr><td>'+data.id+'</td><td>'+data.title+'</td><td>'+data.publishDate+'</td><td>'+data.comments+'</td></tr>';
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(row);
}
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(gridRow);
```

Note: The data comes from the Fixture

Comment: Can I ask—why not use a component for this? I'm sure you have your reasons—just curious

Comment: Hi @ChristopherMilne thanks for your response. Actually the Grid Comp itself is a component. I have posted a snippet from the component.

Comment: If you make the grid-row a component as well, you could pass in data with data=data

Comment: Which version of ember are you using?

Comment: this should be a component

Comment: You should bind Helpers and export the function as default.

Comment: Yes I can make it as a componenet but just curious to know is there any other way to acheive this or the reason for this kind of behaviour. @Kingpin2k I'm using version 1.10.0

Comment: @HasibMahmud  sorry could you please breifly explain the part bind Helpers?

Comment: Have a look http://www.ember-cli.com/#resolving-handlebars-helpers .

Comment: @HasibMahmud The `grid-row helper` is resolved and invoked correctly I forgot to add the last line in the Grid Row helper(updated the question). The problem is the values are undefined.

Comment: Try `data['title']` instead of `data.title`.

Comment: @HasibMahmud I tried with data['title'] but still i'm getting undefined

Comment: You better make it a component.